# How do I check if my Aldous-Broder algorithm is done?

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I'm implementing this algorithm in Java, I understand the algorithm as such, but I don't know when should I stop it. Is there any condition I can check in order to achieve so? I'm implementing a maze generator by the way.

Comment: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/17/maze-generation-aldous-broder-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep track of the remaining tiles. Say your maze has size (n,m) then set a counter to `n*m - 1` and decrease it for any new tile visited and if 0 you're done.